# How to handle optional beans when their availability criteria comes from a database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Consider the following code which configures the polling of some SFTP servers. The configuration comes from a database.

```
@Bean
@RefreshScope
RotatingServerAdvice advice(DelegatingSessionFactory<LsEntry> delegatingSessionFactory) {

    List<RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory> keyDirectories = interfaceRepo.findAll().stream()
            .filter(Interface::isReceivingData)
            .map(x -> new RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory(
                    new SessionFactoryKey(x.getHostname(), x.getPort(), x.getUsername()),
                    x.getDirectory()()))
            .toList();

    return keyDirectories.isEmpty() ? null : new RotatingServerAdvice(delegatingSessionFactory, keyDirectories);

}

@Bean
ConcurrentMetadataStore store() {
    return new PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow(ObjectProvider<RotatingServerAdvice> adviceProvider,
        DelegatingSessionFactory<LsEntry> delegatingSessionFactory, ConcurrentMetadataStore store) {
    
    RotatingServerAdvice advice = adviceProvider.getIfAvailable();

    return advice == null ? null
            : IntegrationFlows
                    .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(delegatingSessionFactory)
                            .filter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(store, "rotate_"))
                            .localDirectory(new File("C:\\tmp\\sftp"))
                            .localFilenameExpression("#remoteDirectory + T(java.io.File).separator + #root")
                            .remoteDirectory("."), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1).advice(advice)))
                    .channel(MessageChannels.queue("files")).get();
}
```

I'm trying to handle the case when the database is empty. I can't create a `RotatingServerAdvice` with an empty `List<RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory>` because there is an `Assert.notNull` in Spring's code, so I'm returning `null` instead of a `RotatingServerAdvice` instance.

In `flow` I tried to handle the `null` case with `ObjectProvider` when I call `getIfAvailable` on it it just returns me a CGLib proxy backed with what I suspect to be a `NullBean` (because `toString()` returns `"null"`).

I have no solution to test if that bean is a `NullBean` or an actual instance of `RotatingServerAdvice` because of the proxy that hides the internal implementation.

Also there is no `@Conditional` annotation that would allow me to query the database.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in some my projects:

```
 @Autowired(required = false) RotatingServerAdvice rotatingServerAdvice
```

However the `IntegrationFlow` is not designed for refreshing: it is a composite logical component to populated Spring Integration beans according to the provided config.

I would suggest to implement some delegating `MessageSourceMutator` which would use that `RotatingServerAdvice` if that is not null, otherwise default method impls. This way you always can inject it into your flow and can mark it with the `@RefreshScope` to be able to re-initialize with newly created `RotatingServerAdvice` delegate. Same `@Autowired(required = false)` injection still applies.